# Efficient way to subtract arrays and get index of resulting subarray

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say I have the following arrays:

```
arr1 = [
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['c', 'd'],
  ['e', 'f']
]

arr2 = [
  ['g', 'h'],
  ['i', 'k'],
  ['a', 'b']
]
```

I want to find the elements in `arr1` that do not exist in `arr2` and the index of the elements in `arr1`

I can do this with the following but this isn't very efficient and is not a pretty solution. There can also be many elements in the arrays so this does not scale. Is there a better way to do this?

```
diff = arr1 - arr2

diff_with_index = diff.map { |x| { index: arr1.index(x), values: x } }

print diff_with_index
# [{:index=>1, :values=>["c", "d"]}, {:index=>2, :values=>["e", "f"]}]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about "the index of the elements in `arr1`". Seems a bit confusing because what if `arr2` does have `"c"` but does not have `"d"`, is that a usecase for you?

Comment: No, that is not a case. For it to be valid it needs to have both elements in the same order. So I need it to operate the same as array subtraction but also get the index

Comment: Just because this is tagged rails can you explain where these arrays come from and why they ate being compared in this way? I find most rails questions that involve sets have a database source and can usually be solved far more efficiently in database rather than in code.

Answer (score 2):

When you have to do multiple `include?` checks, the most efficient way is to turn one of the lists into a set or hash beforehand, so you can have O(1) lookup time, so something like this:

```
require 'set'
arr2_set = Set.new(arr2)
arr1.each_index.select { |idx| !arr2_set.include?(arr1[idx]) }
```

Comment: I should have read your answer before posting mine, which I've now deleted. Note that sets and hashes don't have quite  O(1), though it's certainly a reasonable way of expressing it.

Comment: Given the desired output `filter_map.with_index` is likely the best fit.

Comment: oh yeah my bad i didn't see they wanted the missing element too

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

```
i1 = (0..arr1.size-1).to_a
  #=> [0, 1, 2]
```

```
h1 = arr1.zip(i1).to_h
  #=> {["a", "b"]=>0, ["c", "d"]=>1, ["e", "f"]=>2}
```

```
i1 - arr2.map { |a| h1[a] }
  #=> [1, 2]
```

Note that

```
arr2.map { |a| h1[a] }
  #=> [nil, nil, 0]
```